# Android - AsyncTask return value

Tags: java, android

I am looking to implement a generic type API Handler.  I have created a class called ApiCall that extends the AsyncTask.  The results are returned as a JSONArray.

I am new to Android and don't fully understand how to invoke a function in the Activity Class.  I have seen several posts and blogs in regards to how to do this; however, most of them are either a private class withing the activity class or have some type of call back to the activity or fragment that provides a hard link back to the calling class.

I want to keep this class loosely coupled, to allow me to reuse this throughout the app.

Thank you for your insight.

Comment: Hey Bob!  Wanna put some code here, so we have something to work with?

Comment: Here is the Class:

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a reference as a Weak reference. This will ensure that the class is loosely coupled to any UI elements.

```
     private  WeakReference<CallBack> callBack;
     //To assign a callBack reference to weak reference object
     callBack = new WeakReference<CallBack>(callBackReference);

     //To check if reference to callBack still available
     final CallBack callback = callBack.get();
     if(callback!= null){

      }
```

Comment: To quote Jake Wharton: "A weak reference is either just being lazy and not wanting to properly tie registration to a lifecycle or you are not in proper control of a lifecycle and are guessing when you think unregistration should occur."